# Fetch value of a node's attribute in XML

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an XML document, a snippet of which is below:

```
<item name="entryDataItem" type="dataView" caption="__entry_data_item" id="208" formItem="selectbox"> 
<properties>
  <property name="caption" value="Task Type"/>
  <property name="name" value="task_type"/>
  </properties>
</item>
<item name="entryDataItem" type="dataView" caption="__entry_data_item"  id="211" formItem="text">
<properties>
  <property name="caption" value="Time Spent (Min)"/>
  <property name="name" value="time_spent_min"/>
  </properties>
</item>
```

etc.

There are other "properties" as well. The value of "task_type" as well as all other properties are stored in database. When I iterate through the document, all the properties are fetched and a document is prepared with "caption" and "value" from the XML. The problem is , all the "properties" are printed. But I want contents of the document to be based on the "task_type"; say when the task_type value is TESTING", then only task_type "ESTIMATION" would be printed and nothing else.

I understand I have to put a check just before where the document is being prepared.
My question is: How do I put the condition when I only have "task_type" in the XML and not a value(eg."TESTING") directly within the XML document?

My code is a simple JAVA code.
Any help as to how this can be achived is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to parse the XML and do something based on a property/value of a element in your DOM, or are you saying you are trying to write out the XML, but need to make a decission based on some property/value of a element?

Comment: I want to parse the XML, fetch the caption and values(as seen in the code above), and build a page where these values will show.
But what values would appear on the page would depend on the task_type: eg If the task type is "TESTING" , then the time spent field should not show in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, XPath is the bee's knees when it comes to going after specific items in a XML document.  [This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html) might be of some use if it's something you want to persue.

Comment: Thanks @CodeChimp. Indeed XPath was the bee's knees for the problem.Plus its so simple to implement.